# In Android, open google maps to show multiple markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have several markers with descriptions in JSON format (but I could use another). How would I open this in google maps (v2) from my android application?

Example of the data:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Ice Cream Daydream",
      "description":"OTR;33 E 12th St,</div>Cincinnati, OH 45202<br><img src=",
      "lon":-84.513634,
      "lat":39.108456,
      "tour":"otr",
      "image":""
   },
   {
      "name":"Into the Renaissance",
      "description":"OTR;1519 Vine St,</div>Cincinnati, OH 45202<br><img src=",
      "lon":-84.516068,
      "lat":39.11235,
      "tour":"otr",
      "image":""
   },
   {
      "name":"Know Theater Murals",
      "description":"OTR; </div>1120 Jackson St,Cincinnati, OH 45202<br><img src=",
      "lon":-84.513672,
      "lat":39.108154,
      "tour":"otr",
      "image":""
   }
]
```

Comment: For google maps...please visit:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro

for adding markers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: Will those help with adding multiple in one view?

Comment: multiple markers on one google map is possible.

Comment: Just hard to find an example. I can parse the JSON, but how to get that to the map is where I am wondering

Comment: send me your code. I'll have a look

Comment: how to I send you code?

Comment: send it on my email id. You can find my email on my stackoverflow account.
Or just google "Atish Agrawal" and you can get all my details

Answer (score 1):

In XML file

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In Java File

```
FrameLayout mapContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapContainer);
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapContainer, mapFragment).commit();

mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
             @Override
             public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    GoogleMap  mMap = googleMap;
                    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    addMarks(mMap);
                });
            }
```

ADD Multiple Marker

```
 private void addMarks(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitute, longitute);
            builder.include(latLng);
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(storeLocation);
    }

}
```